# How to handle expressjs rest routes with empty path param with csurf returning 404 instead of 403?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, http-status-codes, x-xsrf-token

I already asked this question to the author of csurf (Douglas Wilson) via Github Issues and he suggested to create a new post on stackoverflow.

The original issue is here: https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/issues/161

My situation is:
I have some apis in express (post, put, get and delete) also with path params.
Some examples:
DELETE /api/users/2376213786213
POST /api/users . (with a body)
and so on

I want to use csurf, but I also want to catch when someone call an api with an empty path param and return a 404.
In short, If you call DELETE /api/users/ (with an empty id as path param) I want to return 404, otherwise if you call DELETE /api/users/12121 I want to handle the csrf token and return 403 if not valid.
Is it possible? How?

I created a middleware to handle csrf like in the official csurf's example:

```
// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err)

  // handle CSRF token errors here
  res.status(403)
  res.send('form tampered with')
})
```

And after this middleware, I created another one to handle 404, nothing special.

However, this api DELETE /api/users/ (with an empty id as path param) is trapped by the first middleware and return 403, instead of 404.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.